# SQL Login Redirecting

Tags: php

I have a login that sets the session var "username" to their username before redirecting to this page:

```
include("../required/header.php");


if (isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
   echo " "; 
} else {
   echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=https://trevorc.ca/login">';  
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>



<body>
<body>
<div class="headout">
<div class="headin">
<b>Home</b>
</div>
</div>
<center>

$name = $_SESSION["username"]; 

echo "Hello " . $name . ", welcome to TrevorC.ca!";


<br><br>

<br>


<br>
<br>
<br>
</center>
</body>
<?php
include("../required/footer.php");
?>
<br>

</html>
```

What I cant figure out is why this is redirecting me away even tho the session variable is set to my username! Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put

```
session_start();
```

At the top of each page where you're using sessions.